# Formal notation for repeating symbols

Tags: notation

I am doing some work in NLP and I am not sure what the mathematical notation is for "repeating symbols inside sequences". Let me give an example using Python.

In python we can simply do this:

```
>>>'c'*5 + 'a'*3
'ccccccaaa'
```

Now my question is very simple; how does one write that formally in math?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

$$\{(x \odot y) \mid x \in \{1,\ldots,C\}, y \in \{1,\ldots,A\}\}$$

where one defines the o-dot as a some sort of 'repetition' operator - though this does seem a bit verbose. Bear in mind that my actual data (the `cccccaaaa` example) has a length of several thousand, so I do need something compact to represent the structure of those strings. Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Like this, $\underbrace{c\dots c}_{\text{5000 times}}\ \underbrace{a\dots a}_{\text{3000 times}}$? Or you can define concatenation power $^{[n]}$ and write $c^{[5000]}a^{[3000]}$.

Comment: The usual notation would be $c^m a^m$, methinks.  This notation is consistent with the notation used for [free groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) and (perhaps more appropriately) [free monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid).